# background task and SQLite in windows Universal 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

I created a project of Windows Universal app. Then I add a new Runtime Component (background task C#) for update my tile.
Then I install sqlite-net for background task. I want to read some data from my database. 
When I want to run my app, I get some error from SQLite.cs.

http://borjianamin.persiangig.com/errors.png

I search a little and I found this Topic: (I'm sorry for this because I don't have enough reputation)
stackoverflow.com/questions/14812076/how-to-connect-to-sqlite-database-from-windows-runtime-component-which-is-for-ru
github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/104

I use replace tool of VS2015 and replace all public with internal But I get about 300 errors this time.

This is my background task project only:
Link: http://www.rodfile.com/uu9viaaxsz91

Is it possible to help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to help me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You have to add a separate project for SQLite called **Class Library**.

[image]

Then you have to add sqlite.net in that class library. After that you need to add the reference of *Class Library* on Windows Runtime Component.